# Button Widget Not Getting Destroyed While Trying To Remove From The Grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

a. Have a scenario where I wanted to remove a button after few clicks.
b. But when the button reaches the last click, its not getting destroyed. 
Code as given below:

```
from tkinter import *

class test_button:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.next_button = None

        if not (self.next_button): 
            self.next_button = Button(root, background="orange red", activebackground="orangered3", text="Next Test Config", command=self.next_button_code).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def next_button_code(self):
        if self.next_button:
            self.next_button.destroy(); self.next_button = None

# Top Local Variables
root = Tk()

# Top Level Default Codes
my_gui = test_button(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Am I missing anything ? Kindly drop in your comments !!

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `self.next_button` is what you think it is? (hint: it's not)

Comment: Some of indentation levels are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
self.next_button = Button(root, background="orange red", activebackground="orangered3", text="Next Test Config", command=self.next_button_code).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

to:

```
self.next_button = Button(root, background="orange red", activebackground="orangered3", text="Next Test Config", command=self.next_button_code)
self.next_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the comments !

Comment: For more information please check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8834940/5601431) answer of [@BryanOakley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley).