# Tkinter update grid contents

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I started working with tkinter in after 6 months of python experience, I'm currently making an smtp mail sender, the only problem is the **widgets in my grid refuse to update based on conditions**. I know its purely my fault because I'm used how non-gui programming works in comparison to *event driven.*

```
import tkinter as tk


class smtp_gui(tk.Tk):

    is_logged_in = False
    user_email = ''
    user_passwd = ''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("SMTP Mail Sender")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap('at.ico')
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        btn_container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", padx=1, pady=1)
        container.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        btn_container.pack(side="bottom", padx=1, pady=1, fill='x')

        tk.Label(container, text='From:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(container, text='To:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(container, text='Subject:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        if self.logged_in():   
            self.mailabel = tk.Label(container, bd=1, text=smtp_gui.user_email, relief='sunken').grid(row=0, column=1, pady=3, padx=2, sticky='we')
        else:
            self.login_btn = tk.Button(container, text="login before sending", command=self.get_login)
            self.login_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we", pady=3, padx=2)

        self.To = tk.Entry(container)
        self.To.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="we", pady=3, padx=2)

        self.Subject = tk.Entry(container)
        self.Subject.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="we", pady=2, padx=2)

        self.Msg = tk.Text(container, width=40, height=5)
        self.Msg.grid(columnspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)

        send_btn = tk.Button(btn_container, text="Send", command=self.send)
        send_btn.pack(side='right', padx=2, pady=1)

        quit_btn = tk.Button(btn_container, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quit_btn.pack(side='right', padx=2, pady=1)

    def send(self):
        print(self.Msg.get("0.0", "end"))

    def logged_in(self):
        return smtp_gui.is_logged_in

    def login(self):
        pass

    def get_login(self):
        login = tk.Toplevel(self)
        login.grab_set()
        login.wm_title("Email login")
        login.resizable(False, False)
        login.iconbitmap('login.ico')
        container = tk.Frame(login)
        btn_container = tk.Frame(login)

        container.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
        btn_container.pack(side="bottom", padx=1, pady=1, fill='x')

        tk.Label(container, text="Gmail address:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(container, text="Password:").grid(row=1, column=0)

        login.Address = tk.Entry(container)
        login.Address.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we", pady=3, padx=2)
        login.Address.insert(0, "your address")

        login.Passwd = tk.Entry(container, show="*")
        login.Passwd.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="we", pady=3, padx=2)

        login_btn = tk.Button(btn_container, text="Login", command=None)
        login_btn.pack(side='right', padx=2, pady=3)

        storno_btn = tk.Button(btn_container, text="Storno", command=login.destroy)
        storno_btn.pack(side='right', padx=2, pady=3)


root = smtp_gui()
root.mainloop()
```

So.. I guess there has to be some way to update grid contents based on conditions or something. I want the window to display a login button if the user didn't login or display his address when he already logged in, the button and the label are in the same place in the grid as you can see in the code.

Thanks for any answers!

**EDIT - The problem can now be reproduced.**

Comment: Why don't you create label objects instead of creating them randomly without assigning them to variables? This way you can reuse and update them wherever in your code you wish.

Comment: Also, not enough code to reproduce the problem. Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually, you have not shown us what you've done so far to solve your problem yourself at all. I've just answered [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130055/button-widget-not-getting-destroyed-while-trying-to-remove-from-the-grid) on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com). I'm sure you could've found many other threads as well that are related to your problem, if you researched with certain keywords. Please don't take this advice offensive, I'm just trying to enlighten new users. So please read about [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Okay, your code is working pretty nice for me now! Now, let me know, in which part of your code you want the `grid` contents to get updated?

Comment: I appreciate that you want to solve my issue, I managed to solve it thanks to that question you mentioned before! Thanks anyways! :)